# Shrink down a curved path by a specific length

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, bezier-curve

Is there a way to shrink a **curved** path (with two open ends) down by a specific length in Adobe Illustrator?

I searched for hours now and still can't find a solution. Do you know any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. What you do is you use the stroke palette with a dashed array with following properties:

- First dash set to the length of curve you need.
- Second dash set to something so big so its longer than path.
- Set dash option to preserve exact dash.

You can then copy the curve and expand this curve and use it for reference for a cut if you need the actual curve shorter. You can also use art brushes for same thing, such as when you hit the upper limit of the dash.

Comment: Cool.. that's kind of what I determined in teh comments below my answer. I figured you may have a more mathematical approach.

Comment: @Metis well i CAn script it but thats a different thing. [SHS](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/) has a script to this effect by the way. As does the [pomax bezierinfo](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) but I dont have time to take my secret sauce out of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Straight or curved?

For straight paths, just enter a new `W` or `H` value in the **Control bar** field or **Transform Panel** with the path selected.

Curved paths are another matter entirely.

Comment: Its curved, sadly

Comment: There's no direct input method for a curved path due to it's having a width, height, and arc. You'd have to move to scripting for curved paths. The best you could due without scripting is control the distance between the anchor points, but that is *not* the same as the length of the path.

Comment: If I remember correctlsy, svg had an option for stroke length, so you could have a sroke shorter than the path. So it should be technically possible I think. I don't know anything about illustrator scripting, what is it?

Comment: Illustrator scripting is essentially javascript... so you have more math function possibilities there to use in order to draw/manipulate objects... http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html Illustrator has no such things as a "stroke shorter than its path" except in the case of dashes. So I guess you could have a path, set to dashed with one dash a specific length. [So, yeah, I guess that's a possibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAmzS.jpg)

Comment: Full disclosure.. scripting AI isn't my strong point... but @joojaa may come along here. He has a fantastic handle on that sort of stuff. If ti's possible, he'll know if he chooses to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to shrink a **curved** path (with two open ends) down by a specific length in Adobe Illustrator?

Yes there is a way... but it is not native to Illustrator.

The answer lies in using PathScribe, found within the [VectorScribe plugin from Astute Graphics.](https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) While this plugin is not free, you can try it out during a free trial period.

One of the tools included with PathScribe is the Extend Path tool. This tool (despite its moniker) can also trim paths as well.

Here I have an open curved path which is 1410px in length:

[image: Starting path]

Assuming you've already installed VectorScribe, click and hold on the PathScribe button, which gives you access to the Extend Path Tool:

[image: Extend Path Tool location]

You'll likely want to constrain your trim to count to full pixels rather than decimal fractions. To do so make sure your Keyboard Increment (found under Edit > Preferences > General) is set to 1px:

[image: Keyboard Increment setting]

Then (with the Extend Path Tool selected) hit the Enter key to go into the Extend Path Preferences... Now check 'Constrain Length by Multiples' and under that check 'Constrain Change in Length':

[image: Constrain changes]

With your path active, hover over the end of the path and you'll see an annotation appear, then just click and drag:

[image: Trim path length by 40px exactly]

You can see from the Info Panel that we have now decreased the total length of our curved path by exactly 40px. Simple!

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way to do this with native tools despite there being an answer that demonstrates to the contrary?

Comment: Wasn't trying to step on your toes... I guess I took the "specific" part of the question to mean "precisely specific".

Comment: When someone says "be specific" they usually mean "exact". My answer speaks to removing **exactly 40 px.** I've tried to follow your instructions but I cannot reproduce the same results on my example using your methods. It is in my experience literally impossible to even get a curved path to be exactly 1410px in length using only Illustrator. let alone to reduce its length by "specifically" 40px! Can you produce a curved path of specifically 1410px? Can you then reduce that same curved path to exactly 1370px using your (unspecified) artbrush method using only Illustrator?

Comment: You've _answered_ to the contrary but I don't think you've really and truly "demonstrated" it.

Comment: Yes no problem, i can make a curve exactly 20px shorter with inbuilt tools. Note that the length of a bezier curve is not exact anyway. The method illustrator uses to calculate the bezier is only correct within  0.01 px anyway.

Comment: Hmmm... The Document Info panel displays to 3 decimal points, so... Anyhow, if so that's just all the more reason to use PathScribe for me! The Extend Path Tool seems to be accurate to one ten-thousandth of a pixel.

Comment: you dont understand, its not possible to calculate the exact length of a bezier. So what you have is a LIE it tells you a value with xxx decimals but the underlying system is not calculating stuff to that accuracy. So what you have is a numeric lie on top of an approximation. Its 3 decimals accurate to a value thats not as accurate. Its still off since the numbers themselves are off.  Also Illustrator has a nasty way of changing decimal precision when you save since PDF is storing not floats or double floats but rather fixed points.

Comment: Please provide examples: One path as 1410.XXXpx and one precisely 40.000px less at 1370.XXXpx... I don't believe this can be done natively in Illustrator (but it can be done with the Astute Graphics plugin). I asked the folks at Astute Graphics about your assertions and their reply states that while your statements may have been true at one time, the accuracy of path length calculations was improved dramatically with the introduction of CS6, and the implementation of floating point arithmetic. In my experience path length is retained after saving and reopening.

Comment: improved yes but the function of the arc length of a Bezier can not be calculated with absolute precision so claiming that you are absolutely accurate is bullcrap. Obsessing about a thousandths of a point is irrelevant as a PDF file can not have that kind of accuracy

Comment: Why do you keep referring to PDFs? I save my Illustrator documents as AI files. I can create a path (using Astute Graphics plugin) which displays as exactly 1410px with no decimal points. I can then reduce the length of that path to display as exactly 1370px with no decimal points. Can you reproduce this using Illustrator alone? Please provide proof of your assertions.

Comment: Why, what is in it for me?

Comment: Here, you can download my examples, and open them up in Illustrator to see that they are exact lengths with no decimal points... Here is [1410px](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuHlnnjoOa2lhOEeECtmq6HNHIFo_A) and here is [1370px](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuHlnnjoOa2lhOEdetdaDDP6CRV_rA). Screenshots: [Exactly 1410px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDcPz.png) and [Exactly 1370px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvVbD.png) Please provide your own examples...

Comment: Thats irrelevant a) we do not now what the underlying precision of the bezier length approximation is. We are approximately accurate to something approiximate B) no output system (pdf or eps sent to printer or svg for web) can output it from illustrator without custom stuff. C)  When it gets rasterized its irrelevant the rasterizer is not taht accurate. D) If its going to be output by a vector imaging system like a lasercutter then the inaccuracies of bezier is irrelevant anyway because nobody in their sane mind would do thios accurate things with illustrator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60696/discussion-between-joojaa-and-bang).

Answer (score 0):

*If* the path is *only slightly curved* towards the end, and nobodies' life depends on it, you can of course draw a circle at the end of the path:

[image: Screenshot of circle at the end-node of the path]

Draw the circle using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while dragging and make sure its' center has snapped to the last node of the path. Enter the amount you want to trim as the W and H value of the circle.

Then, select the path and use the **scissors** tool ( <kbd>C</kbd> ) to cut the path where it intersects the circle. (Illustrator will 'snap' the tool to the intersection if you have 'smart guides' enabled.)

*Disclaimer*: this is reasonably precise. But not exact. So, it might not answer the question well enough. But maybe, it's still useful for others.